# uploadify doesn't display properly in IE

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I've been using uploadify for about an hour now and think its great but I've just checked it in IE and the queue doesn't display. The file uploader still works and does everything it's supposed to but the queue just doesn't display so it appears as if it's doing nothing. I have the latest flash player so it can't be that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it. Must have been some conflicting styles cos i deleted some stuff from my stylesheet and it works now

Comment: getting this exact issue but can not determine what it could be.